# Manually add labels separately (or together) by factor levels to barplot ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a barplot with two factor levels with mean.

This is my dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(supp=rep(c("A", "B"), each=3),
            dose=rep(c("D1", "D2", "D3"),2),
            len=c(2, 4, 3, 15, 40, 29.5))
```

In the first case I want to add mean values separately to every column, but in case of factor "A" above the column, and in case of factor "B" on the column. I have tried this:

```
library(ggplot2)    
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=dose, y=len, fill=supp)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) +
  geom_text(aes(label=len),position = position_dodge(0.9), 
  vjust=c(-1.6,1.6,-1.6,1.6,-1.6,1.6), 
        color="black", size=3.5)
```

And I want this type of graph:

[image]

In the second case I want to add own factor levels name to columns together every second column (by the second factor). I have tried this:

```
library(ggplot2) 
factor2 <- c("Dose I.", "Dose II.", "Dose III.")   
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=dose, y=len, fill=supp)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) +
  geom_text(aes(label=len),position = position_dodge(0.9), 
  vjust=c(-1.6,1.6,-1.6,1.6,-1.6,1.6), 
        color="black", size=3.5) +
  geom_label(aes(label=factor2), y=45, color="black", fill="white", fontface = "bold", size=3)
```

And this is the final plot:

[image]

Can somebody help me? Thank you.

Comment: Running the second example, I get `Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (6): label`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code as posted didn't work in the second example, because factor2 was length 3, and ggplot2 doesn't automatically recycle the same way R does. Another problem with your code is that you specified a y value of 45, which is way above the maximum len observed. By scaling this relative to the max observed len (I chose `max(len) / 5` but that's arbitrary), it'll always be visible (assuming you don't have negative values...).

```r
library("ggplot2")    
df <- data.frame(
  supp = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 3),
  dose = rep(c("D1", "D2", "D3"), 2),
  len = c(2, 4, 3, 15, 40, 29.5),
  factor2 = c("Dose I.", "Dose II.", "Dose III.")
)


ggplot(
    data = df,
    aes(x = dose, y = len, fill = supp)
  ) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = len),
    position = position_dodge(0.9), 
    vjust = c(-1.6, 1.6, -1.6, 1.6, -1.6, 1.6), 
    color = "black",
    size = 3.5) +
  geom_label(aes(x = dose, y = max(len) / 5, label = factor2), inherit.aes = FALSE, 
    color = "black",
    fill = "white",
    fontface = "bold",
    size = 3
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-01-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

There are two questions in one.

#### Answer to the first part

I suggest to add `vjust` to `aes()` and scale manually:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df) +
  aes(dose, len, fill = supp, label = len, vjust = supp) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(0.9),
            color = "black",
            size = 4) + 
  scale_discrete_manual("vjust", values = c(A = -0.5, B = 1.5), guide = FALSE)
```

Note that `vjust` normally varies from 0 to 1, and is centered at 0.5.

[image]

#### Answer to the second part

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to print labels on the large bars of the second factor `supp == "B"`.

One possibility is to modify the plot data `df` by appending a column with the additional label text.

```
df$factor2 <- c(rep(NA, 3L), "Dose I.", "Dose II.", "Dose III.")
```

Now, `df` has become

```
df
```

> ```
>   supp dose  len   factor2
> 1    A   D1  2.0      <NA>
> 2    A   D2  4.0      <NA>
> 3    A   D3  3.0      <NA>
> 4    B   D1 15.0   Dose I.
> 5    B   D2 40.0  Dose II.
> 6    B   D3 29.5 Dose III.
> ```

```
ggplot(df) +
  aes(dose, len, fill = supp, vjust = supp) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_text(aes(label = len),
            position = position_dodge(0.9),
            color = "black",
            size = 4) + 
  scale_discrete_manual("vjust", values = c(A = -0.5, B = 1.5), guide = FALSE) +
  geom_label(aes(y = min(len[supp == "B"]) / 2, label = factor2),
             position = position_dodge(0.9),
             color = "black",
             fill = "white",
             fontface = "bold",
             size = 4)
```

[image]

Note that the labels are plotted centered to the bars of the second factor. The vertical position `y` is computed dynamically from the height of the smallest bar of the second factor (note that the `vjust` aesthetic is applied here as well).

The bars of the first factor have not been labeled because `factor2` is `NA` for the respective rows.